# Inserting data into multiple tables with spring jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc

I am working to insert n number of records into two tables with using java, spring jdbc template. some like this

assume daos.xml correctly configured.

```
ApplicationContext ctxt = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("daos.xml");
JdbcTemplate template = (JdbcTemplate) ctxt.getBean("jdbcTemplate");

final List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i =1; i<=100; i++){
            Person item = new Person();
            item.setFirstName("Naveen" + i);
            item.setLastName("kumar" + i);
            item.setDescription("D" + i);
            list.add(item);

            Role role = new Role();
            role.setName("Admin");
            role.setCode("c"  + i);
            roles.add(role);

        }

String sql = "insert into person(first_name, last_name, description) values(?,?,?)";

            int[] arr = template.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

                        @Override
                        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException                             {
                            Person person = list.get(i);
                            ps.setObject(1, person.getFirstName());
                            ps.setObject(2, person.getLastName());
                            ps.setObject(3, person.getDescription());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public int getBatchSize() {
                            return list.size()
                        }
                    });
```

I am also configured Transaction Manager.

So my question is how can i insert data into both person and role table using batch. Because Person can have role. when i insert into person it require role id to be insert together. In this case person insertion query will looks like this.

```
String sql = "insert into person(first_name, last_name, description, role_id) values(?,?,?, ?)";
```

I want to perform it into batch batch. because in my case i have min 10k person list to parse using file. So it can be a performance killer i insert role into table than get it and they insert person again.

Comment: If you have 10K records, consider use the project **Spring Batch**. I would use the JdbcTemplate's **batch** method only for few records, for example the details of an invoice, where they would be 1 to 20 for an invoice.

Comment: I want to insert record into two different table. Let say Role and Person table. I have to parse a file which may consist 10k record in one shot. So after parsing data from file into Role and Person object then I want to insert first Role Object and then get the inserted Role object id and then insert Person object which have role. So my problem is i want to maintain transaction as well as batch processing to so that no round-trip toward db. Now can you please tell me right approach to achieve the following task. What is Spring Batch and how can be used. Give me any link of example.

Comment: Hi, Spring Batch covers your requirements, and has Transaction support, and has something important, "chunks" you can have 10 chunks of 1K with transactional support. FYI http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/

Comment: thanks a lot. I am also found it and working on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use multilane statements and `LAST_INSERT_ID()` MySql function:

```
String sql = "insert into role(name, code) values(?,?);" +
    "insert into person(first_name, last_name, description, role_id) values(?,?,?,(SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()));";

int[] arr = template.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
        Role role = roles.get(i);
        Person person = list.get(i);
        ps.setObject(1, role.getName());
        ps.setObject(2, role.getCode();
        ps.setObject(3, person.getFirstName());
        ps.setObject(4, person.getLastName());
        ps.setObject(5, person.getDescription());
    }

    @Override
    public int getBatchSize() {
        return list.size()
    }
});
```

Comment: Dear Nailgun, First Question - Will it be the right approach when multiple thread is concurrently running to insert this kind of data.means getting the last id. Second question - how i will insert role. If i use jdbcTemplate.update(). then again it is thousands of hitting towards db. Thats why i was looking some solution to person this two insertion into single batch execution.

Comment: 1) LAST_INSERT_ID() returns last id inserted from the current connection so that's ok 2) Then you need to little change your code to use `public <T> int[][] batchUpdate(String sql, final Collection<T> batchArgs, final int batchSize, final ParameterizedPreparedStatementSetter<T> pss)` method from `JdbcTemplate`. I recommend to set `batchSize` parameter to 1000.

Comment: Thanks, i hope it will work. I also did same thing as are telling.

Comment: In Postgres the Multiline Insert with `;` doesn't work: `PSQLException: Too many update results were returned.` See: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/373352.78463.qm@web32701.mail.mud.yahoo.com

Comment: you can use CTE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567741/how-to-insert-batch-for-multiple-table-using-spring-namedparameterjdbctemplate/67380135#67380135

Comment: Hi, I have a similar case to insert data into two different tables but I am getting PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar at the second insert statement. any comments please. code is exact the same as above.