# How to insert batch for multiple table using Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring

```
public int insertUser(User user) {
      String query = "insert into named_demo.user_details (f_name, l_name, email, password) values(:f_name, :l_name, :email, :password);
      +
     "insert into named_demo.media (user_id, media_type, media_url) values ((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()), :media_type, :media_url);";
    Map<String, Object> namedParameters = new HashMap<>();
    namedParameters.put("f_name", user.getFname());
    namedParameters.put("l_name", user.getLname());
    namedParameters.put("email", user.getEmailId());
    namedParameters.put("password", user.getPassword());
    namedParameters.put("media_type", 1);
    namedParameters.put("media_url", user.getMediaUrl());
    int[] value = jtemplate.batchUpdate(query, namedParameters);
}
```

Here I try to use batch processing in spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and insert data in multiple table.
**.** I try to insert data in user details table and i want to get table primary id using **((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID())**and insert into media table.
Can it possible by NamedParameterJdbcTemplate or we can use another approach. If anyone tried to before, please let me know.
Tnank you

Comment: That will never work. Also alternating statements will never be batch processed so even a batch update wouldn't work. Insert all the user_details, then query the id when inserting the media. By executing a select for the inserted user.

Comment: Ok, fine But the one query in my mind, multi table batch can possibly by NamedParameterJdbcTemplate or not. If you have any link to find out example please share. Thank you

Comment: It isn't a single query so no. It will only work if you are using the same query. This has nothing to do with how the template works but how JDBC batching works.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to insert two tables at once using CTE query in postgresql:

```
with first_insert as (
    insert into address (address_description, address_type)
        values ('test', 0)
        returning id)
insert
into address_geometry(id, geom_text)
select id,'test2'
from first_insert;
```

You can wrap this query into another CTE to make 3 inserts, and so on.

Comment: I too have same requirement, @7er, Can you please suggest how to do that with CTE, I dint get with above snippet