# Postgres Batch-Insert into 2 Tables where Table2 Needs ID from Table1: a Multi-Insert with “;” not allowed

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-jdbc, batch-insert

I posted a similar thread on StackExchange DB Administrators, but maybe there will be additional tips here as well.

I need to Batch-Insert data into 2 tables, and Table2 has an FK ID from Table1, so I need to obtain the ID that was just inserted into Table1 for each Table2 row. This is with Postgres, from a Java program, using `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()`.

Table1 = `USERS_T` Table2 = `STUDY_PARTICIPANTS_T` has an FK: `USER_ID = USERS_T.ID`

**Problem**

Suppose I'm using Postgres' `currval('users_t_id_seq')` to obtain the sequence value used by Table1.

One way to batch-insert into 2 tables is sequential, but this won't work because the `currval` will have just the latest row's ID, so all the Table2 inserts will be messed up, and just have the single latest Table1 ID value which is wrong.

```
// Part 1: Insert into USERS_T
batchInsertUsers(jdbcTemplate, batchInsertUsers);
// Part 2: Insert into STUDY_PARTICIPANTS_T
batchInsertStudyParticipants(jdbcTemplate, batchInsertUsers);

private void batchInsertUsers(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, final List<UsersT> batchInsertUsers) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO USERS_T (ID, .., ..) " + 
                 "VALUES (nextval('users_t_id_seq'), .., ..";
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
       //...
    });
}

private void batchInsertStudyParticipants(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, final List<UsersT> batchInsertUsers) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO STUDY_PARTICIPANTS_T (ID, USER_ID, ..) " + 
                 "VALUES (nextval('study_participants_t_id_seq'), 
                          currval('users_t_id_seq'), .., ..";
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
       //...
    });
}
```

Another way to "catch" the latest ID is to do a multi-line insert for both tables, as follows -- that way I could catch the latest `USERS_T` sequence value.

I was following the [suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24589257/1005607) where a poster recommended a multi-line INSERT with `;`.

But in Postgres, this gives the following error:

```
PSQLException: Too many update results were returned.
```

I can't use `;` to separate my 1-line INSERTS, and this is documented here, https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/373352.78463.qm@web32701.mail.mud.yahoo.com

```
private void batchInsertAll(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, final List<UsersT> batchInsertUsers) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO USERS_T (ID, .. ) " + 
                 "VALUES (nextval('users_t_id_seq'), ..) " + 
                 ";" +   // Note semicolon separating my multiline SQL
                 "INSERT INTO STUDY_PARTICIPANTS_T (ID, USER_ID, ..) " + 
                 "VALUES (nextval('study_participants_t_id_seq'), 
                          currval('users_t_id_seq'), .., ..";
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
       //...
    });
}
```

So I can't find a way to do a 2-Table Insert and catch the appropriate Table1 ID in this Postgres Batch-Insert process.